# Highcharts - multiple axial ordered

Tags: axis

Do Highcharts have (or working) on multiple axial like this ?
https://www.fusioncharts.com/charts/line-area-charts/line-chart-with-multiple-axes-and-series?framework=javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they have. In fact, we've got an array of axes, so we can have several of them.

API references:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis

Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/eu6omtg1/

```
yAxis: [{}, {
 opposite: true
}, {}, {
 opposite: true
}],
```